# Placing cursor and focus inside contenteditable div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click on my `td` the hidden div will display over the top of it and the div will be made `contenteditable` but I want the mouse cursor to appear in the so after a single click I can start typing. Currently you need to click twice -- once to focus, and again to place the cursor.

Please don't worry about why I'm doing it this way, I've just stripped my code down to the essentials to isolate this problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
    $("td").on("mousedown", function() {
        var cellOffset = $(this).offset();
        $('#cellSelect').offset({ top:cellOffset.top-1, left:cellOffset.left-1 });
        $('#cellSelect').show(0);
        $('#cellSelect').attr('contenteditable','true');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cellSelect" style="display:none;position:absolute;border: 2px solid blue;width:91px;height:91px"></div>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100" height="100">
    <tr>
        <td id="1-1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `focus` on the element.

You'll need to wrap the `focus` call in a `setTimeout` to ensure that the element is editable before focusing, otherwise you won't be able to type.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
    $("td").on("mousedown", function() {
        var cellOffset = $(this).offset();
        $('#cellSelect').offset({ top:cellOffset.top-1, left:cellOffset.left-1 });
        $('#cellSelect').show(0);
        $('#cellSelect').attr('contenteditable','true');
        setTimeout(() => $('#cellSelect').focus(), 0)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cellSelect" style="display:none;position:absolute;border: 2px solid blue;width:91px;height:91px"></div>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="100" height="100">
    <tr>
        <td id="1-1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: whats the use of setting timeout to 0?

Comment: @seriously If you don't, you'd be focusing on the element before it was editable.

Comment: uhh yeah i get that but 0ms means not time out then how is the settimeout setting a delay without a time set? ) isn't a time in time-space if you get what I'm trying to say .

Comment: @seriously Setting the second parameter to `0` will schedule the callback to be executed after the shortest possible delay, which is realistically 10ms.

Comment: so with this relation what would 1ms be realistically?

Comment: @seriously 10 milliseconds.

Comment: oh got it so set timeouts lowest acceptable time value is 10ms. Thanks